# Multiple TCP Client configuration

Tags: spring-boot, sockets, spring-integration, tcpclient

I am designing a Spring boot application with spring integration to connect to TCP servers.
There will be multiple servers (not a part of this application) for which we would need those many clients (part of application). Once the socket connections are established, it needs to be maintained and reused for all communication. Depending on an identifier (server id), we need to use the appropriate client socket connection to send messages to an appropriate server.

Previously we have done this using netty where we dynamically create connections during application startup and store it in a `HashMap<String, SocketConnectionHandler>` where the key is the server id.
`SocketConnectionHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler`
SocketConnectionHandler provided channelRead and channelWrite which were used for communicating with the server.
If a new server was added, only the configuration needed to be changed and no application deployment was needed.

Can we achieve the same functionality using spring-integration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; this sample does exactly that...

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client

> **Dynamic TCP Client**

> Demonstrates a technique to dynamically add TCP clients on-demand, with caching and LRU removal.

> Uses the Spring Integration Java DSL Runtime flow registration feature.

> The code starts two inbound channel adapters on ports 1234 and 5678 and sends a message to each.